# Webview not able to load WebApp which Chrome can load

Tags: android

I have a `webapp` which when loaded in **chrome** on an Android phone works fine.

Once I try to load the same `webapp` with the same url etc in a **webview** from an android app it fails. Currently it fails when the web app tries to make an **ajax** call and get a `404 error`. But as it works in any other browser I doubt the problem lies with the web app, but rather with the **webview**.

Your first thought might be the internet permission in the manifest? Nope its there since the first load!

This is the code I use, I have pretty much tried to enable anything I can think of that might block an **ajax** call:

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        webView.settings.blockNetworkLoads = false
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true

        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        } else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                view!!.loadUrl("$url/embedded/override")
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
            }
        }

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onConsoleMessage(message: String, lineNumber: Int, sourceID: String) {
                Log.w("Web Viewer", "$message -- From line $lineNumber of $sourceID")
            }

            override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage?): Boolean {
                consoleMessage?.apply {
                    Log.w("MyApplication", "${message()} -- From line ${lineNumber()} of ${sourceId()}")
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        webView.loadUrl("https://webapp url")

        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            webView.reload()
//            swipeRefresh.
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What API are you running on, what is the version of Chrome that works and what is the WebView implementation used by your app (check it in developer settings)?

Comment: WebView uses "Chrome Stable" and the chrome version I use is the stable one from the store (80.0.xxxx)

Comment: you have getting any error ?

Comment: in logcat nothing. In the webview console using chromes remote debugging only the 404 error.